# Can't apply border-radius in IE8 using PIE.htc

Tags: html, css, css3pie

my code:

```
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
behavior: url(./PIE-1.0.0/PIE.htc);
```

this code is inside a `css` file not in html markup.
I include all the files that comes with the zip package [css3pie](http://css3pie.com/) in a subfolder where my css file is.

May it be becasuse I'm not using css3? How can I now if I'm using ccs3?

Comment: please check your path of your pie.htc. The path must be relative to the html-page, not to the css-file. Is that the case?

Comment: It's your path as Sven points out, CSS3 has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I've asked this question, here are a bunch of different answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175056/cant-get-css3pie-to-work

Comment: @Sven, post your comment as answer please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your path to the pie.htc. The path has to be relative to the html-page, not to the css-file. That is an often made error when linking an htc file.